# Disprove convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor nx \rfloor}}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

A question found in a Russia exercise book, but with no answer.

Disrove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor nx \rfloor}}{n}}$ is uniform convergent in $(1,2)$.

Comment: not sure you read that right since the series doesn't converge for $x=2/3$ for example as it is $1-1/2+1/3+1/4-1/5+1/6+1/7...$ as is easily seen; more generally it will diverge for all rational numbers with even numerators in lowest form

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the question, (1) is divergent obviously, I have edited and deleted (1).

Comment: why do you think that makes any difference; see $x=4/3$ for which $3k+2, 3k+3$ give plus and $3k+1$ gives minus; if $x=\frac{2p}{2q+1}$ in lowest terms, the signs depend only on the remainders mod $2q+1$ which are odd in number, so they cannot distribute evenly, hence the series diverges

Comment: note that it is a difficult result of Davenport (which includes PNT for $x=0$) that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\mu(n)(-1)^{\lfloor nx \rfloor}}{n}}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$ to $\frac{4\sin \pi x}{\pi}-\frac{2\sin 2\pi x}{\pi}$

Answer (score -1):

Not a proof:

Since

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor nx \rfloor}}{n}}=\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k} \right) \left( \sum_{k=\lfloor nx \rfloor}^{}{\frac{1}{n}} \right) =\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k} \right) \left( \sum_{k^2/x\leqslant n<(k+1)^2/x}^{}{\frac{1}{n}} \right),$$

we need to estimate $\sum_{k^2/x\leqslant n<(k+1)^2/x}^{}{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Use E-M Formula, we can get

$$\sum_{k^2/x\leqslant n<(k+1)^2/x}^{}{\frac{1}{n}}=\int_{k^2/x}^{(k+1)^2/x}{\frac{1}{n}}\mathrm{d}u-\left. \left( u-\lfloor u \rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{1}{u} \right|_{k^2/x}^{(k+1)^2/x}-\int_{k^2/x}^{(k+1)^2/x}{\left( u-\lfloor u \rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{1}{u^2}}\mathrm{d}u,$$

For the left side,

\begin{align*}
|LHS|&\leqslant \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{k} \right) +\left. \left( u-\lfloor u \rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{1}{u} \right|_{k^2/x}^{(k+1)^2/x}+\int_{k^2/x}^{(k+1)^2/x}{\left| u-\lfloor u \rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \right|\frac{1}{u^2}}\mathrm{d}u
\\
&\leqslant \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{k} \right) +x\left( \frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \right) +\int_{k^2/x}^{(k+1)^2/x}{\left| u-\lfloor u \rfloor -\frac{1}{2} \right|\frac{1}{u^2}}\mathrm{d}u
\\
&\leqslant \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{k} \right) +O(k^{-2})+O(k^{-3}).
\end{align*}

Comment: this is incorrect since the series doesn't converge for $x=4/3$ for example since then $[(3k+1)x]=4k+1, [(3k+2)x]=4k+2,  [(3k+3)x]=4k+4$ so the series is just $-1+1/2+1/3-1/4+1/5+1/6..$ which obviously diverges since $\frac{1}{3k+1}-\frac{1}{3k+2}=O(1/k^2)$ hence the partial sums are unbounded due to the $1/3+1/6+...$ terms; one mistake is using the divergent oscillating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k}$ to multiply with anything

Comment: Yes, this is divergent, and the above is the disproof. The original question is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{nx} \rfloor}}{n}}$ with a sqrt. Sorry for my mistyping, I have changed the question QWQ

Comment: that one is convergent except at $0$ and uniform on any compact that avoids zero but the proof is not that easy

Comment: I would suggest making another question if possible with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{nx} \rfloor}}{n}}$

Comment: and incidentally the series in this post is convergent at irrational points and at rationals that are either odd/odd or odd/even in lowest form like  $1, 1/2, 1/3, 3/4, 3/5$ etc

Comment: Thanks for your help QwQ